# Hibernate One To Many Problem

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, postgresql

I am doing a proof of concept for one to many mapping with no success. My schema is as follows:

```
Student ---->Phone
```

class Student

```
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable 
{
   private Set<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers = new HashSet<Phone>();
   // other setters and getters and constructors
}
```

class Phone

```
public class Phone implements java.io.Serializable 
{ 
  private Student student;
// other setters and getters and constructors
}
```

Student Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 5, 2010 7:56:05 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Student" table="STUDENT">
        <id name="studentId" type="long">
            <column name="STUDENTID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="studentName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="STUDENTNAME" />
        </property>
        <set name="studentPhoneNumbers" table="PHONE" inverse="true" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="STUDENTID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Phone" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Phone Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 5, 2010 7:56:05 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Phone" table="PHONE">
        <id name="phoneId" type="long">
            <column name="PHONEID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="phoneType" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PHONETYPE" />
        </property>
        <property name="phoneNumber" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PHONENUMBER" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="student" class="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Student" not-null="true">
            <column name="STUDENTID" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But when I am doing this:

```
            Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Set<Phone> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<Phone>();
        phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("house","32354353"));
        phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("mobile","9889343423"));

        Student student = new Student("Eswar", phoneNumbers);
        session.save(student);

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.BiddingSystem.domain.Phone.student
        at org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:313)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:144)


    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
        at 

org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:689)
    at com.BiddingSystem.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService.processCall(PersistentRemoteService.java:174)
    ... 21 more
```

Can someone help in setting the proper attributes for this
phone mapping xml file

```
<many-to-one name="student" class="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Student" not-null="true">
            <column name="STUDENTID" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

and Student mapping file

```
<set name="studentPhoneNumbers" table="PHONE" inverse="true" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="STUDENTID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Phone" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push the Student object into the Phone objects:

```
foreach (Phone phone : student.getStudentPhoneNumbers()) {
    phone.setStudent(student);
}
```

A more typical piece of code would create the Student instance first, and then add the phone numbers to it. I've often implemented a method to help with this, e.g. in Student.java:

```
public void addPhoneNumber(Phone phone) {
    phone.setStudent(this);
    getStudentPhoneNumbers().add(phone);
}
public void addPhoneNumber(String type, String number) {
    addPhoneNumber(new Phone(type, number));
}
```

So now you can say `student.addPhoneNumber("home", "12354")` and it will simply DTRT.

Comment: Cab someone help me in setting the attribute for this

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Bi-Direction association with inverse=true option, the child objects will be persisted independently. The parent object doesn't take care about synchronization with child objects. So in this case, there will one insert query for parent object and as many insert query as the child objects. So, child object need to have reference of parent object at insert time. Also you have defined not-null=true at parent as well as child side.

When we use inverse=false, parent will be saved first, then child will be saved without reference of parent object and at last the parent will update its relationship with child using the update queries.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1). Phone number must have a student so create a student object (stu = new Student()) first and
 then call phone.setStudent(stu);

ex:

```
   Set<Phone> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<Phone>();

   Phone p1 = new Phone("house", "32354353");

   phoneNumbers.add(p1);
   Phone p2 = new Phone("mobile", "9889343423");
   phoneNumbers.add(p2);

   Student student = new Student("Eswar", phoneNumbers);
   student.setPhones(phoneNumbers);
   session.save(student); //Till now, This code is work if you use cascade = 'all' in            //my_mapping_file.xml or

   session.save(p1); session.save(p2); //call session.save on both phone objects
```