# One-to-many relationship with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Hibernate with Spring and Hibernate return this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'ID_TAREA_FK' cannot be null
```

I have two classes

```
public class Tarea {
 private List<Sesion> sesiones;
}

public class Sesion {
 private Tarea tarea;
}
```

With their getters and setters. In my code, I don't forget

```
t.getSesiones().add(s);
s.setTarea(t);
```

The database tables are:
TAREAS { ID_TAREA, ... }, SESIONES { ID_SESION, ID_TAREA_FK, ... }

The pieco of code in Tarea.hbm.xml for the list sesiones is:

```
<bag name="sesiones" table="SESIONES" inverse="true" cascade="all">
 <key column="ID_TAREA" not-null="true" />
 <one-to-many class="com.jonasurbano.tareas.domain.sesiones.Sesion" />
</bag>
```

In Sesion.hbm.xml:

```
<many-to-one name="tarea" class="com.jonasurbano.tareas.domain.tareas.Tarea" not-null="true">
 <column name="ID_TAREA_FK" />
</many-to-one>
```

What am I doing wrongly? I've read Hibernate documentation and this post [Hibernate One To Many Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363218/hibernate-one-to-many-problem) but it doesn't work for me.

After working out this problem, I would like to know if there is some way to avoid the reference Tarea in class Sesion because I think this property is redundant.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check your database constraints. Probably `ID_TAREA_FK` has `not null` constraint, try to remove this constraint, because Hibernate saves the identity column first with null values at all other columns.
- Delete <strike>not-null="true"</strike>.

  ```
  <key column="ID_TAREA" />
  ```
- Rewrite mapping in one string:

  ```
  <many-to-one name="tarea" class="com.jonasurbano.tareas.domain.tareas.Tarea" not-null="true"  column="ID_TAREA_FK"/>
  ```

Read this if something wrong with mapping and nothing helps you http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-bidirectional

Comment: I've had to delete not-null="true" for ID_TAREA_FK too... But it works ;)

Comment: wonderful coms, thank you for the tip with deleting not-null=true. Solved my problem.